# Hajós Number vs. Chromatic Number

Tags: probability, combinatorics, discrete-mathematics, probabilistic-method

The Hajós number of a graph $G$ is the largest $k$ such that there are $k$ vertices
in $G$ with a path between each pair so that all $k \choose 2$ paths are internally pairwise vertex disjoint
(i.e. if a vertex is not one of the $k$, then it appears on at most one such path), and none of the
$k$ vertices is an internal vertex of any of the paths. Is there a graph whose chromatic number
exceeds twice its Hajos number?

The problem is from the book *Probabilistic Methods* by Noga Alon.

Comment: What does that book indicate about the status of this problem?  Is it said to be an "open problem", or is it simply assigned as an exercise for the Reader?

Comment: See [The Probabilistic Method (3rd. ed.)](http://onlinelibrary.wiley.com/book/10.1002/9780470277331) by Noga Alon (Wiley, 2008).

Comment: @hardmath I have seen the forth edition. But it only has a hint to consider G(n,0.5)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hint: Consider $G(n,\frac{1}{2})$

Every set contains almost half of edges $w.h.p.$

So you need at least one vertex for almost half on $k\choose2$ which is greater than total number of vertices if $k$ is large enough.

Comment: I can't understand your statement. Every set contains almost half of edges? Every set of what? It's unclear to me, can someone explain further?